# Interprocess communication sending structure via pipe

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pipe

I have to show the elapsed time to run a command using pipes, so I use the gettimeofday function and pass the pointer through the pipe, but when I'm reading it in the father process I get a different result than expected. I'm supossed to get 1604626608037896 but instead I have this 94762421350317.
This is my code:

```
    if (pipe(p) < 0)
        exit(1);
    pid=fork();
    if (pid == -1){
        printf("can't fork, error occured\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }else if (pid == 0){
        //This is the child I get the time 
        gettimeofday(&current,NULL);
        //I write it in the pipe, if I print the time here i get the result I want
        write(p[1], &current, sizeof(current));
        close(p[1]);
        //then I execute the command
    }else{
        //this is the parent
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) > 0){
            close(p[1]);
            struct timeval inicio;
            //Here is the problem I think, once I tried to read it I get a random number
            read(p[0], &inicio, sizeof(inicio));
            printf(": %ld,%ld\n", inicio.tv_sec,inicio.tv_usec); 
            
        }else{
            printf("waitpid() failed\n");
        }
        exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are expecting that the `if` block runs in the child process and `else` block is running in parent process and the `fork` is called before the code segment. In that case the `p` in two process are different for two process and they are not connected.

Your `read` call if throwing a error. Can you check the return value at of the `read` system call?

The modified code snipped should looks like

```
    if (pipe(p) < 0)
        exit(1);
    if (fork() < 0)
        exit(1);
    if (pid == 0){
        //I get the time 
        gettimeofday(&current,NULL);
        //I write it in the pipe, if I print the time here i get the result I want
        if (write(p[1], &current, sizeof(current)) < 0) {
            perror("write");
            exit(1);
        }
        close(p[1]);
        //then I execute the command
    }else{
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) > 0){
            close(p[1]);
            struct timeval inicio;
            //Here is the problem I think, once I tried to read it I get a random number
            if (read(p[0], &inicio, sizeof(inicio)) < 0) {
                perror("read");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf(": %ld,%ld\n", inicio.tv_sec,inicio.tv_usec); 
            
        }else{
            printf("waitpid() failed\n");
        }
        exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Yes the if block is supossed to be the child and the else part the parent and they have to communicate using the pipe, I did what you mention, and the read syscall is returning 0, then how can I connect the p to  communicate the two processes?

Comment: Well, my problem was that I was calling the fork before the pipe call, so the p was definitely not connecting the processes, thanks